# Unable to connect to DB from VBA but able to connect from Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, connection-string

I'm able to connect to a database using Access, but not from VBA.  In Access, I use the server name, Windows NT Integrated Security,and the database name.  In VBA, I've tried many variations of variable names and values in the connection string, and the db.Open command always fails. I generally get an error about not being able to find an installable ISAM, or Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors.  Is there a way to determine what I can use as a connection string from the working Access connection? One example of code that fails with the latter error:

```
Dim db As Object
Dim adoRS As Object
Set db = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set adoRS = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
db.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Server=sql03;" & _
"Database=db1;" & _
"Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

Comment: What type of database are you connecting *to*?

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 0):

The provider you as using in the connection string is for MS Access.
If thats the correct database then do the following.
Add the refrence "Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine object library.

```
Dim cnString, query As String
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

'If older version of MS access then try Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;'

cnSTring= "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=<Path>;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=<Pass>;"
query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE"    
rs.Open query, cnString, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```